# Adding Href Via JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a phone number clickable using jquery. There is existing css code and jquery to create the html, however I cant seem t add a href.

Tried changing the span class to include href, when added the phone number doesnt appear

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $phone_number2 = "International 00-1-250-586-9928";
  jQuery("span#et-info-phone").after("<span class=info-phone-2>" + $phone_number2 + "</span>");
  jQuery(".info-phone-2").attr("href", "tel:00-1-250-586-9928");
});
```

```css
span.info-phone-2 {
  position: relative;
}

.info-phone-2:before {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  content: "\e090";
}

.info-phone-2 {
  margin-right: 13px;
}

.info-phone-2:before {
  font-family: "ETmodules" !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  speak: none;
}
```

Comment: Spans don't have an href attribute, anchors do

Comment: Change `span` to `a`.

Comment: Side point(ignoring the span issue); You're using string concatenation to add the text to the span.  Why not concatenate the href in there as well?

Comment: @Barmar I did that and now the phone number doesnt appear

Comment: Please update your question to show your updated logic.

Comment: Also if you changed your `span` to an `a`, your `span.info-phone-2` css rule will have to change as well

Comment: You should only change the element that you're adding with `.after()`, not th span you're adding to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anchor rather than a span.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $phone_number2 = "International 00-1-250-586-9928";
  jQuery("span#et-info-phone").after("<a class=info-phone-2>" + $phone_number2 + "</a>");
  jQuery(".info-phone-2").attr("href", "tel:00-1-250-586-9928");
});
```

```css
a.info-phone-2 {
  position: relative;
}

.info-phone-2:before {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  content: "\e090";
}

.info-phone-2 {
  margin-right: 13px;
}

.info-phone-2:before {
  font-family: "ETmodules" !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  speak: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="et-info-phone">Phone: </span>
```